# How to plot this graph using Python properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the graph bellow using python, but I am getting an error.

[image]

The Python commands I am using are:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_csv('data/filtro_bovespa_final.csv')

data.loc[(data['codigo'] == 'BBAS3') & (data['codigo'] == 'BBDC4')]

data.date = pd.to_datetime(data['date'],format='%Y%m%d')
data.set_index(['date','codigo'])
plt.plot(data.date,data.preco)
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is:

I got this graph, but it is not what I need:

[image]

The csv file I am using: [Bovespa](http://www.mediafire.com/file/lp2473n5urd2nmd/filtro_bovespa_final.csv/file)

I need a graph that allows me to compare the price linked with both the codes (BBAS3 and BBDC4) as the first graph I showed.

What else should I do to get the graph I need?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `data.plot` and `data.show`. Do you mean `plt.show()`?

Comment: Judging from the error message, it seems to be `data.show`, what happens if I comment out?

Comment: I corrected it... but I got another error... I have updated the question.

Comment: Do the graphs match the data you've presented?

Comment: Yes... the data I presented is on the graph of the figure I uploaded here. I n eed to plot this same figure using python... however, it is not working. Hope you can help me.

Comment: **the obly thing that is different is that preco = preco/100 on the graph I have uploaded... it does not change the code, anyway.

Comment: I am ploting a graph now but it is not what I need. I have updated the question with the new code.

Answer (score 2):

To draw them by attribute, we use a pivot to turn the data frames into columns by attribute. I've also changed the extraction condition to OR.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('./Data/filtro_bovespa_final.csv')
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data['date'],format='%Y%m%d')

data = data.loc[(data['codigo'] == 'BBAS3') | (data['codigo'] == 'BBDC4')]
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)
data = data.pivot(columns='codigo')
data.columns = ['BBAS3','BBDC4']

data.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]